# Laravel phpunit assertViewHas doesn't match the expected test data

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am writing a test for my search method, but had currently a assertSee and want to change it for a assertViewHas for a better test result. But the data that I get from the search method does not want to match the data I expect.

This is where I set `$user`:

```
protected $user;

public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    $this->seed();

    $this->user = factory(User::class)->create(['role_id' => 3]);
}
```

This is where I'm making the assertion:

```
$response = $this->followingRedirects()->actingAs($this->user)->get('/manage/users/search?choices=username&search='.$this->user->username.'');

$response->assertViewIs('manage.users');
$response->assertSuccessful();
$response->assertViewHas('users', $this->user);
```

And this is the data it will return from the controller:

```
$result = User::where('username', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->get('search') .'%')
                ->orderBy('username', 'asc')->paginate(20);
return view('manage.users')->with('users', $result);
```

What am I doing wrong to get the matching data?

Comment: You are trying to assert that the view has a `$users` variable that matches `$this->user`. But `$users` is an instance of `LengthAwarePaginator` (because you are using `paginate()`) and `$this->user` is probably an instance of the `User` model.

Comment: Do you know a solution for that?

Comment: How are you defining `$this->user` in your test? Add it to your question.

Comment: @Camilo added it to my question

Comment: So you are trying to assert that a given user is contained in the `$users` variable passed to the view?

Comment: @Camilo yeah but one is from the LengthAwarePaginator instance and one is a User model and don't know how I can match those like I want in my question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to assert that `$this->user` matches `$users` from your controller. But `paginate()` returns a `LengthAwarePaginator` instance and `$this->user` is an instance of `User`, so they won't match.

If you want to assert that a given user is contained in the `$users` variable passed to the view, you could pass a closure to `assertViewHas()` with the necessary logic.

Maybe something like this:

```
$response->assertViewHas('users', function($users) {
    return $users->contains($this->user);
});
```

You can view how `assertViewHas()` works on the [Laravel source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.php#L569).