# Laravel test with paginator object issue

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, phpunit

I got a simple controller that just show data in blade template.

```
public function index()
    {
        $title = "Our list of genres"; 
        $genres = Genre::paginate(20);
        return view('lists-view.genres-list',compact('genres','title'));
    }
```

And test for this controller

```
//        Fill database
        (new Genre())::factory(20)->create();
//        Get 20 genres
        $genres = Genre::paginate(20);

        $response = $this->get('/genres');

        $response->assertStatus(200);

        $response->assertSee("Our list of genres");
        $response->assertViewHas('title', "Our list of genres");
        $response->assertViewHas('genres',$genres);
```

The issuie in this line
`$response->assertViewHas('genres',$genres);`
Error code:

```
  Failed asserting that two objects are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
     'items' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object (...)
     'perPage' => 20
     'currentPage' => 1
-    'path' => 'http://books-store.loc'
+    'path' => 'http://books-store.loc/genres'
     'query' => Array ()
     'fragment' => null
     'pageName' => 'page'
     'onEachSide' => 3
     'options' => Array (
-        'path' => 'http://books-store.loc'
+        'path' => 'http://books-store.loc/genres'
         'pageName' => 'page'
     )
     'total' => 20
     'lastPage' => 1
 )
```

Can somebody tell me what i'm doing wrong? I can change paginator's path by $genres->setPath('correct path') but i can not change options and should i change them at all?
Maybe it's another way to write this test?

I want to check "is data given from controller to view is correct"

Comment: You can get an idea what wrong you're doing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47576072/laravel-phpunit-assertviewhas-doesnt-match-the-expected-test-data

Comment: I saw it and I can say - it's different issues. Thanks for your try. It looks to me like paginate method is not usable in PHPUnit tests and is much better to rewrite my code somehow else.

Comment: So, you will get a URL formed in the test when you call `paginate`, because you are not inside a "url", the Router just returns `/`, so the `path` is your domain `APP_URL`. But in you controller, you are inside `/genres`, that is why it is setting it like that.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, the problem was solved and I just forgot about this topic. The solution is extremely simple - paginate method returns an object with a method called items and method items return an array of data from a database. The better way is to compare two arrays of data from the test and from the view.